# UnicodeDecodeError: skipped file requirements.txt in . (reason: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte)

Tags: python, django, internationalization, gettext

I was installing gettext without any problem and suddenly I got this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: skipped file requirements.txt in . (reason: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte)
processing locale es
```

What catches my attention is that this appears: **processing locale es**. That is to say that if it was installed?

Comment: It seems as if the file ./requirements.txt isn't encoded in UTF8, but some other codec. So, if you open it with some editor and save it using UTF8, this problem should be gone.
What I don't understand: What does it have to do with gettext?
And when exactly does this error occur? So, what are you trying to do, to provoke it? Fetch translations?

Comment: yes, in fact I want to translate the django site but it seems that with gettext I have problems, I don't know if there is an easier way to do it

Comment: Nah, gettext is the right way to do. I'm just surprised that it's complaining about requirements.txt. 
Does this happen, when you "makemessages" with django-admin?
And did you try to save the requirements.txt again and force encoding in UTF8?

Comment: Exactly, it happens when I make messages

Comment: And did you try to convert this dubious requirements.txt into UTF8?

Comment: No I didn't try; but then that could be a solution for my problem?

Comment: Yes, it should solve your problem.
makemessages goes through all files and requires them to be UTF8 encoded.

Comment: ooh thank you very much for your answer, it has caused me too much